# aliasing component and multiple select

Tags: c#, .net

Can I give alias to components?
Example:
I have textbox1.text then I named that textbox1.text to "abc"
then if I give that textbox1.text a value, I just run this code :

```
abc = dgv.rows[1][1].value.ToString();
```

or

If I have multiple textbox, can I select all that textbox?
Example:
I have textbox1, textbox2, textbox3 then I will reset text all that textbox
can I select multiple textbox?

```
textbox[1][2][3].ResetText();
```

It will be a convenient way when I have more than 15 textbox controls on the form.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? This would only make the code less readable and is far from common practice. As for selecting multiple textboxes. i'm afraid you can't. Instead, loop through all textboxes in a given container and set their text appropriately.

Comment: im just curious, it was always thought in my mind. i just practicing, maybe someday that code will be more be useful

Comment: Im going to post an explanatory answer below so you can grasp the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I would like to show you why this approach would not be proper.

**Case one - giving aliases**

Look at those two codes( first is our 'pseudo c# code' if there were aliases, it won't acutally work)

```
public void changeTextBoxName(TextBox textBox)
{
    TextBox.Value = value;
    value.ToString() = toStringValue;

    int number = 5;
    number.toStringValue;
}
```

Now, compare it with this (actual C# example):

```
public void changeTextBoxName(TextBox textBox)
{
    int number = 5;
    TextBox.Value = number.ToString()
}
```

This might have been an overexaggeration, but still - it looks so much worse.
Also, remember that when programming, youshould stick to the common practices, so that one day when someone reads your code (at work for example) he will not go "hella I'm out" in 5 seconds but will actually understand what you had written.

**Case two - grouping**

This one is just purely impractical. You maybe write 5 lines of code less, but you would still have to resort to the original method when dealing with many items.

Look at the code and compare for yourself (same case as above):

```
TextBox[0][1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10].Value = "Hello!";
```

Now, compare with the actual example:

```
foreach (TextBox tb in MyGrid)
{
    tb.Value = "Hello!";
}
```

I hope my examples helped you to understand why it is the way it is. Cheers :)